# Question relating to Bolzano Weierstrass property?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then $X$ is compact implies $X$ have Bolzano Weierstrass property.

I want to know  theorem of this converse. That is:

> Every subset of compact topological space need not be compact?

Can anybody provide me any counter example or any hint?

I could not able to find out the counterexample. I was thinking about $X = [0,1]$... but no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but surely $(0,1)$ is a non-compact subset of the compact metric space $[0,1]$.

I think the theorem you are citing is that every compact metric space has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property, which I believe is the statement that bounded sequences have convergent subsequences. If this is true, you are asking if it is possible to have a compact metric space in which a bounded sequence has no convergent subsequence. In which case, the answer is no. This property is also known as 'sequential compactness'and this is equivalent to being compact for metric spaces. However, for more general topological spaces, they are not equivalent.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space

Comment: I think what you meant to say was "....if it is possible to have a $compact$ metric space in which..."

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lots Alfred Yerger